# How to create a cross-region read replica for AWS RDS With CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I’m wondering how I can exactly create a read replica in a different region than my default region. Though I searched high and low I couldn’t really find an answer to the following questions:

- do I need to create a new ADMIN user in my AWS account tied to the region where I want to create the Read Replica or can I set it up with my standard Admin account.

  - do I need to create a separate CF template from my regular RDS template containing only the instructions for the READ Replica and launch it with the other admin account by logging in the other account or can I somehow launch it using my regular Admin account

I’m actually trying to find the most efficient solution how to set up cross-region Read Replicas via CloudFormation.

Merci A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one user (you can just switch regions in the console. Or if using the CLI/SDK set the region parameter). You will need a separate stack/template that is deployed in the other region for the read replica.

Comment: @ cementblocks, thanks thats what i thought as well alas the create-stack command in CLI has no —region option...https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html; how can I launch the stack (I already have the separate template) in the other region using AWS CLI?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html#cli-aws
region is a parameter for all services (except a couple global ones)